# Using unicode correctly in Python 2.7, Ubuntu 13.4?

Tags: python, unicode

In the latest Ubuntu, with the default Python (2.7.4), I can't get unicode to work. This is what's happening:

```
>>> print('tři')
tři
>>> d = {3:'tři'}
>>> d[3]
't\xc5\x99i'
>>> d = {3:u'tři'}
>>> d[3]
u't\u0159i'
```

Obviously, I'd like the third and/or the fifth line to show the same as the first line.

I tried fiddling with sys (import it, reload it, then setdefaultencoding('utf-8')), but it didn't seem to help. Everything else is working normally with unicode, as far as I can tell (it being a modern version of a popular distro and all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should point out that you're playing with the introspection there. Python 2 is storing the unicode the only way it knows how but it's not corrupting the data and the interactive console is showing you that. It's showing you the raw string.

If you want to see the output properly, use `print`:

```
>>> d = {3:'tři'}
>>> print d[3]
tři
```

---

Python 2.x still treats Unicode as something magical and scary. Python 3 treats all strings as unicode. If possible, I'd probably recommend using Python 3.

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.1 (default, Jul  5 2013, 09:19:20) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('tři')
tři
>>> d = {3:'tři'}
>>> d
{3: 'tři'}
>>> d[3]
'tři'
```

It's not always that simple. Python 3 has some peculiar backwards-incompatibilities so if you need certain libraries (or have tons of your own incompatible code) this isn't really an option.

Comment: too bad python 3.x isn't backwards compatible

Comment: @Joren As I say, how much that matters really depends on the project. For a random script with few external dependencies, I doubt it makes much difference at all.

Comment: Thanks! I'd have used Python 3 right away, but sadly, it's not available on the system I'm developing for.